# How to solve UTF-8 in java

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, utf-8, character-encoding

I currently use

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

in my jsp page.

And when I get data from textbox using `request.getParameter("...");` it retrieves data like that `Ã¶É?É?É?Ã¶Ä°` . I saw this problem when I used characters that are not english chars. I add `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` to `server.xml` in tomcat. But it retrieved the same `(Ã¶É?É?É?Ã¶Ä°)`. How to solve it?

Thank you

**EDIT**

Thanks for your answers. I tried a few things, but nothing has fixed the problem.

Here's what I've done:

- I added `<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" .../>` in server.xml.
- `<meta ... charset=utf-8>` tag is ok and I tried `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`
- I also tried `<filter>` tag in web.xml

None of these actions fixes the problem. I'm wondering if there's something else wrong with this...(remembering: I used `<form method='post'>`. I click submit button and when I get data using `request.getParameter("..")` the format of this data is not the correct format. )

Comment: See this related post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281236/jsp-form-encoding

Comment: Are the Strings hard coded into your Application or read from Property file?

Comment: Also even so its not that clean you may need to set the enviorment variable at startup -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

Comment: The Ã is helpful here. It represents byte C2 in Latin-1. It's also the continuation byte for a two byte UTF-8 character. Your form is submitting UTF-8 and your webapp is interpreting as UTF-8.

Comment: *ahem* "Interpreting as Latin-1".

Comment: any solutions didnt solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code in your Servlet

```
if(request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: request.getCharacterEncoding() was null, but it didnt solve my problem

Comment: Maybe you could also try `response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=UTF-8")`

Answer (score 2):

May be because the actual character encoding is not UTF-8 ? If the characters itself are encoded in some other format then we just can't label them as UTF-8.

Try decoding them by giving various charset and see which one gives proper result. I think the input character encoding is latin1(ISO-8859-1). If yes, follow below code

```
String param1 = request.getParameter("...");
if(param1!=null)
{
  param1 = new String(param1.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

UTF 8 should be set at all the layers of the application.

Do following

1) HTML Code

```
 <meta contentType="text/html; charset="UTF-8"/>
```

2) Browser Setting for IE
 View -- Encoding -- Unicode (UTF-8)

3) Tomcat Server
 server.xml - In Connector tag added "URIEncoding" attribute as

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

catalina.sh/catalina.bat - added following

```
set JAVA_OPTS=--Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Xss268k -server -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

set CATALINA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
```

4) MIME type of response should be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: 1 and 2 are ok. 3rd - I added URIEncoding to 'server.xml'. where is catalina.sh/catalina.bat ?

Comment: In the bin directory of your Tomcat installation

Comment: Step 3 was helpful for me!

Comment: However, I used `open -e /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/7.0.42/bin/catalina`, and I omitted the "set" in each line when I was setting the JAVA_OPTS and CATALINA_OPTS.

Answer (score 1):

There is another place you can check. Did you include following declaration in your JSP file?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I think the problem is that browser still sends requests using default [ISO-8859-1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html), which is the standard charset if not declared.

You can also check the HTTP headers received from server to make sure the correct charset is sent back.

Comment: Checking the headers is very important. Also, the Tomcat FAQ page on character encoding is helpful. http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the cleanest way to do it is to use [Unicode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html) in your property files and/or code if need be (not adviced).

This way you avoid all encoding issues, since your programm only has deal with ASCII code, the proper reprenstation is then handeled entierly by the client side and you do not have to worry about the standard os encoding or enviorment encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try adding the following filter at web.xml:

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>Character Encoding Filter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>encoding</param-name>
   <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

**You should try it**

```
String content= request.getParameter("content");
if(content!=null)
  content = new String(content.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```