# changing the encode characters for Eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, encoding, java-ee-7

How do I to change the encoding on Eclipse ?

I did all of these configurations:

> ```
> http://uploads.siteduzero.com/files/388001_389000/388662.png
> http://uploads.siteduzero.com/files/388001_389000/388661.png
> http://uploads.siteduzero.com/files/388001_389000/388660.png
> http://uploads.siteduzero.com/files/388001_389000/388659.png
> ```

And

```
Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > 'Other UTF-8'
```

But, I still get this on my webpage which I had extracted from my DataBase, knowing that the encoding there is perfect (JSP page) :

> `http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/136324Capturer4.jpg`

and I wrote this in the top of my JSP page :

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

and this into head tags of my page

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: You need to describe your problem better. At least I cannot understand

Comment: @JunedAhsan Yeah ..Actually OP described the problem in form of Images.Check those url's mentioned :0. It's very difficult to understand.

Comment: Is it a Jsp page ?? html ? .txt file ?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607828/how-to-change-the-default-default-encoding-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

If you add the next argument in the `eclipse.ini`:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

And you create a new workspace or delete the `.metadata` directory in your current workspace (in that case, you can lost your custom configurations, like formating, cleanup...), all configurations (for Java, XML, console, JSP, HTML...) have, by default, `UTF-8` encoding.

In another way, if you are using Glassfish 4 (for Java EE 7), the default encoding charset is defined by the operative system. You can check that if you test with a JSP or Servlet and print:

```
System.getProperty("file.encoding")
```

Comment: where can I find `eclipse.ini`

Comment: The `eclipse.ini` is in the same directory as `eclipse.exe` if you are using a normal distribution of Eclipse (eclipse.org).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the layers upto your jsp are sending ht eUTF-8 chars properly. Just try setting this on top of your jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Comment: I've putted this in my page, but it doesn't work, I don't know why :/

Comment: @LucieLeighAllen That means your jsp is not getting the UTF-8 data from the backend java code. Can you debug that?

Comment: I've this line on my jsp page: `<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`.Otherwise, how do I debug that please ?

Comment: @LucieLeighAllen need to look into your entire code structure and how are you getting that text to be displayed in jsp. Are you getting that text from java code?

Comment: @LucieLeighAllen I believe we need to move on chat or other place to see your code and find hte problem

Comment: then, where can we chat please

Comment: @LucieLeighAllen through some screen sharing tool

Answer (score -1):

I would guess you need to set the contentType in the response header to text/html and character set to UTF-8.

Comment: I did that, check my posted links http://uploads.siteduzero.com/files/388001_389000/388660.png

Comment: Look at this:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968472/how-to-solve-utf-8-in-java

This might be of some help to you!

Comment: It couldn't fix my issue xD