# How to change the *default* default encoding in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, character-encoding

Every time a new workspace is created, Eclipse defaults to Cp1250 encoding.

Whenever I create a new branch of the project, and as result switch to a new workspace in Eclipse, I need to go to [Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace : Text file encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751791/how-to-change-default-text-file-encoding-in-eclipse) and manually switch to "Other: UTF-8". If I forget this step, Eclipse mangles the UTF-8 characters in the project files.

[image]

Can I change the default somehow, permanently, so that all new workspaces start as UTF-8 without need to switch them manually?

Comment: Did the answers provided answer your question at all? Is there any additional information you can provide to help get a better quality answer?

Comment: @JonahGraham: They are certainly promising. I have to test them in reality and if I find one working okay, I'll surely accept it (if both work fine, I'll pick the one that was easier to implement). Too many questions on this site have an accepted answer that just doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it is quite simple:

Create a **defaults.ini** file in the Eclipse configuration folder. For example, if Eclipse is installed in `C:/Eclipse` create `C:/Eclipse/configuration/defaults.ini`. The file should contain:

```
org.eclipse.core.resources/encoding=UTF-8
```

If you want to set the line terminator to UNIX values you can also add:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime/line.separator=\n
```

In **eclipse.ini** in the Eclipse install folder (e.g., `C:/Eclipse`) add the following lines:

```
-plugincustomization 
D:/Java/Eclipse/configuration/defaults.ini
```

You might need to play around with where you put it. Inserting it before the "-product" option seemed to work.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the key things that [Eclipse Oomph](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/november/article2.php) was created to solve, the ability to set default default preferences, i.e. preferences set across workspaces.

You can go "whole hog" and adopt using Oomph as a full [Eclipse Installer](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Installer) and share the install scripts between your team members. The installer can configure everything from which plug-ins to install, to default preference values, to where to check code out from.

### Preference Recorder

However, for now you can simply use the [Preference Recorder](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/november/article2.php).

1. Install Oomph, it is possibly already installed if you are using Eclipse Mars. If not, from the Mars update site you can install "Oomph Preference Management"
2. Open the preferences page, you should now have a new icon next to Help in the bottom left. It will allow you to turn on/off the preference recorder:

[image: pref recorder icon]

3. With the recorder on, change your preferences you want, in this case your encoding, then press OK. You will then be asked if you want to track the changed preferences across your workspaces. You can change the values in the User Policy column.

[image: select]

4. Now if you create a new workspace, those tracked preferences will be applied to the new workspace.
5. If you want to see what is being recorded, in Preferences, see Oomph -> Setup Tasks -> Preference Recorder

[image: show recorded]

6. To access the full setup configuration, press the button to the right of the `Record Into` drop-down (top right of UI) and the setup file will be opened in the editor, where you can do further control and mods:

[image: editor]

PS. the default default of the encoding is a hotly contested issue at Eclipse, hopefully the default default will change to UTF-8 everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be determined by this code in `org.eclipse.ui.WorkbenchEncoding`:

```java
/**
 * Get the default encoding from the virtual machine.
 */
public static String getWorkbenchDefaultEncoding() {
    return System.getProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
}
```

So it is taken from the 'file.encoding' environment variable, defaulting to 'UTF-8' if that is not set.

Comment: I checked the (*system* and *user*) environment variables and I don't have file.encoding set... is it *yet another* set of environment variables I don't know about? Or maybe a version thing (Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1))

Comment: Presumably you do `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in your eclipse.ini (after `-vmargs`)

Comment: I'm not sure what sets it but if you look in 'Help > Installation Details' on the 'Configuration' tab you should see the value in the list. As suggested you could set a value in the eclipse.ini

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding

Comment: @Jonah Graham is right. Modifying eclipse.ini worked for me on eclipse juno and mars.

Answer (score 2):

in eclipse.ini add :
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8