# Special characters (äöü) not shown correctly in eclipse tree view plug in

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, treeview

I am developing an eclipse plugin with a simple tree view.

I have the problem that in some distributions of eclipse (Luna, Kepler, Mars) the special characters (äöü) in the tree entries are not shown correctly. Just some cryptic letters appear. Strange thing is, that in my installation (mars2) everything is displayed correct. After comparing lots of settings in the different distributione I could not figure out what setting or plug in is influencing this behaviour.

Any hint that brings me further to a solution is appreaciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an encoding problem. This might help you (or at least point you in the right direction): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607828/how-to-change-the-default-default-encoding-in-eclipse

Comment: Where are you getting the accented characters from? Are you sure the Unicode values are correct in the Java strings that you set in the tree? Can the font the tree is using display these characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from [greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) I am reading the sources now directly encoded in UTF8:

```
            BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                           new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
```

Surprisingly this also diplays the characters in the tree view correctly ... :-)

Thanks for the help!